# Reisebank currency exchange

Tags: money, exchange

I'm gonig to travel to Berlin in a week and I want to know the fees charges to convert from foreign currency to Euro currency?

I tried google and browse around their web but I unable to retrieve wanted information.

Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: Which foreign currency? And where are you flying from? Options to convert include eg at the airport (often the most expensive), at your bank or an exchange bureau, or you can use your ATM card in Berlin. Fees for the latter will be published by your card provider. There isn’t always a fixed fee, sometimes the exchange rate ‘turn’ is lower instead.

Comment: Check their currency exchange rate. Normally German banks take only hidden fee (split), which is, however, quite high.

Answer (score 3):

Fees are typically hidden in the way that they advertise 'no fees' but use an unfavorable exchange rate. So knowing the fee is of little help.

You are probably better (=cheaper) off with an ATM card on a normal ATM machine.

Comment: I see.. OK sure. many thanks for the kind information. :)